# Getline Issue in C++

Tags: c++, getline

I have a text file that displays the following:

```
John    Smith    21    UK
David   Jones    28    FRANCE
Peter   Coleman  18    UK
```

and I am trying to strip each individual element into a vector array. I have tried using the getline function with a tab delimiter but it stores every element. For example:

```
getline (f, line, '\t');
records.push_back(line);
```

How can I seperate it line by line? The idea is to perform a search and output the corresponding line. A search for Jones will print out the second line for example.

This is what I have so far but as you can see, it's not giving me the desired outcome:

```
string sString;
string line;
string tempLine;
string str;
vector<string> records;

cout << "Enter search value: " << endl;
cin >> sString;

cout << "\nSEARCHING\n\n";
ifstream f("dataFile.txt");

while (f)
    {
    while(getline (f, tempLine))
    {
       getline (f, line, '\t');
       records.push_back(line);
    }
    for(int i=0; i < records.size(); i++)
    {
       if(sString == records[i]) {
        cout << "RECORD FOUND" << endl;
        for(int j=0; j < records.size(); j++)
        {
            cout << j;
            cout << records[j] << "\t";
        }
        }
    }

}
f.close();
```

Comment: I don't think I am being clear. I want it to store each word on the line into an array, check to see if a field in the array matches the search string (sString) and then if it does, print out the array. then it repeats the process again for the next line and so forth

Comment: I'm unclear on what you want to go into your vector. Can you give an example of what the string `records[0]` should be , etc.?

Comment: Do you mean that the vector should contain all lines which match the string? (similar to `grep`)?

Comment: certainly. records[0] = John, records[1] = Smith, records[2] = 21, records[3] = UK.  I am trying to figure out how to take each word and store it in array until it hits \n, do what i need with the array, clear the array and start on the next line. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `getline` extracts a complete line from the input.
The second extracts one field from the next line.  If you want
to recover the lines broken down into fields, you should do:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> records;
std::string line;
while ( std::getline( f, line ) ) {
    records.push_back( std::vector<std::string>() );
    std::istringsream fieldParser( line );
    std::string field;
    while ( std::getline( fieldParser, field ) ) {
        records.back().push_back( field );
    }
}
```

This will result in a vector of records, where each record is
a vector of fields.  More often, you would want to use a struct
for the record, and do a bit more parsing on the line, e.g.:

```
struct Field
{
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
    int age;
    std::string country;
};
std::vector<Field> records;
std::string line;
while ( std::getline( f, line ) ) {
    std::istringsream fieldParser( line );
    Field field;
    fieldParser >> field.firstName >> field.lastName >> field.age >> field.country >> std::skipws;
    if ( !fieldParser || fieldParser.get() != EOF ) {
        //  Error occurred...
    } else {
        records.push_back( field );
    }
}
```

(Something this simple will only work if none of the fields may
contain white space.  But it's simple to extend.)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `getline` into `tempLine` which eats a whole line, then you are doing a different getline in the loop as well.  That's a big part of why it doesn't work--you are simply throwing away `tempLine` which contains a lot of your data.

Comment: I can see this now. Thanks for pointing that out! I guess I am trying to figure out how to take each word and store it in array until it hits \n, do what i need with the array, clear the array and start on the next line. Does that make sense? It's confusing me greatly